# Keep null values as null in PySpark dense_rank()

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to sort within partitions based on a column that contains nulls.

This DataFrame can be created as follows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame( 
                      [("2019-01-01", 5),
                       ("2019-01-01", 20),
                       ("2019-01-01", 10),
                       ("2019-01-03", 1),
                       ("2019-01-03", None),
                       ("2019-01-03", None),
                       ("2019-01-03", 2),
                       ("2019-01-05", 10)],
                       ("Date", "value")
)
```

Which looks like:

```
+----------+-----+
|      Date|value|
+----------+-----+
|2019-01-01|    5|
|2019-01-01|   20|
|2019-01-01|   10|
|2019-01-03|    1|
|2019-01-03| null|
|2019-01-03| null|
|2019-01-03|    2|
|2019-01-05|   10|
+----------+-----+
```

Now I would like to rank each value from 1 to `N` per date. Which I attempt to do with the following code:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("value")
df = df.withColumn("rank", F.dense_rank().over(w))
```

However, this apparently ranks all `null` values as 1, regardless of how many `null` values there are in a column:

```
+----------+-----+----+
|      Date|value|rank|
+----------+-----+----+
|2019-01-03| null|   1|
|2019-01-03| null|   1|
|2019-01-03|    1|   2|
|2019-01-03|    2|   3|
|2019-01-05|   10|   1|
|2019-01-01|    5|   1|
|2019-01-01|   10|   2|
|2019-01-01|   20|   3|
+----------+-----+----+
```

How can I change the behavior of `dense_rank()` such that it keeps `null` values at `null` when ranking, instead of giving these values an arbitrary rank of 1?

Comment: @Menmo Van Dijk did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is an `isNull()` conditional on both partitioning and the actual ranking. Unfortunately it's not possible to modify `dense_rank()` directly in `pyspark`. Code would look like:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

common_condition = f.col("value").isNull()

w = Window.partitionBy(
    f.col('Date'),
    f.when(common_condition, 1).otherwise(0)
).orderBy(f.col("value"))

df = df.withColumn(
    "rank", 
    f.when(common_condition, f.lit(None)).otherwise(f.dense_rank().over(w))  
)
df.show()

+----------+-----+----+
|      Date|value|rank|
+----------+-----+----+
|2019-01-03|    1|   1|
|2019-01-03|    2|   2|
|2019-01-03| null|null|
|2019-01-03| null|null|
|2019-01-05|   10|   1|
|2019-01-01|    5|   1|
|2019-01-01|   10|   2|
|2019-01-01|   20|   3|
+----------+-----+----+
```

Alternatively, you could play around with `pyspark.sql.functions.desc_nulls_last()` and subsequently filtering out where `f.col("value").isNull()` and your rank column `f.col("rank")` is equal to the partitioned `f.max()` but that is perhaps even clunkier and harder to read.